# Custom ListView to handle EditText and TextView passed from another Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I'm working on creating two Activites and passing data from the second Activity to the first Activity with an Intent. The first Activity, **MainActivity.class**, will hold a ListView that will be initially blank/empty. The second class **AddItemActivity.class** contains an EditText field, a TextView, and a Button. The end goal is to send the content from the EditText and TextView from AddItemActivity to be added to the MainActivity ListView as a new list item which displays the value of EditText on the left and the value of the TextView next to it in the same list item. I have tried passing the values of EditText and TextView via an Intent trying both putExtra() as well as Bundle. How would I be able to accomplish this task? Thank you in advance for any advice/assistance!

Comment: i think your problem could be solved by using another singleton class. In the singleton class use a List that holds each item,add item from AddItemActivity.class and  call notifyDataSetChanged() on onResume() of MainActivity.

Comment: Could you kindly provide some code perhaps? I'm slightly confused as to what you mean.

Comment: Yeah i knw, you'll be, evrybdy will be. cuz it need some code. but i am sorry, i've no time here, have to go to school. if you don't solved your problem before the evening, then i will help you. now i've to go bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start AddItemActivity activity for result.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

```
//Set result on AddItemActivity
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
// TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
resultIntent.putExtra("textView", textView.getText().toString());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: So doing that, when I format the edittext and textview in the intent how would I pass the two fields through the intent? And do you know how I could feed the activity result into the listview?

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit you made! That code snippet was ABSOLUTELY PERFECT!!!! Thank you so very much for your assistance!!!